# Add two signed integers, given in stdin(space separated) in i386 ASM Linux ABI

Tags: performance, assembly

```
.global _start
_start:
    mov $0x1000,%edx
    mov %edx,%eax
    neg %eax
    and %eax,%esp
    mov %esp,%ecx
    xor %ebx,%ebx
    mov $3,%eax
    int $0x80
    add %edx,%esp
    mov %ecx,%edi
    mov $label00,%ebp
    jmp parse_eax_load_constants
label00:
    push %eax
    inc %edi
    mov $label01,%ebp
    jmp parse_eax
label01:
    mov %edi,%ebp
    mov %esi,(%edi)
    dec %edi
    pop %edx
    add %edx,%eax # finally
print_eax: # %edi: where to print %eax
    xor %edx,%edx
    div %esi
    or %cl,%dl
    mov %dl,(%edi)
    dec %edi
    test %eax,%eax
    jnz print_eax

    mov %ebp,%edx
    sub %edi,%edx
    inc %edi
    mov %edi,%ecx
    xor %ebx,%ebx
    inc %ebx
    mov $4,%eax
    int $0x80
    mov %ebx,%eax
    int $0x80

parse_eax_load_constants:
    mov $10,%esi
    mov $0x30,%ecx
parse_eax: # %edi: the string to parse
    xor %eax,%eax
    movb (%edi),%al
    mov %edi,%ebx
    inc %ebx
    cmpb $0x2d,%al
    cmovz %ebx,%edi
    setz %bl
    push %ebx
    mov (%edi),%al
    xor %ebx,%ebx
    xor %cl,%al
parse_eax_loop:
    inc %edi
    movb (%edi),%bl
    xor %cl,%bl
    cmp %esi,%ebx
    jae parse_eax_end
    mul %esi
    add %ebx,%eax
    jmp parse_eax_loop
parse_eax_end:
    pop %ebx
    mov %eax,%edx
    neg %edx
    test %bl,%bl
    cmovnz %edx,%eax
    jmp *%ebp
```

Comment: You have to provide some context to the code, otherwise you won't get appropriate reviews. Why did you write it this way?

Comment: @RolandIllig I wrote this assembly as an exercise; and also to learn i386 assembly(from a x86_64 background)

Answer (score 5):

You are asking for a code review, and my first bit of feedback is: COMMENTS.

Please, reading raw assembler is a challenge.  Start by a comment block at the top that describes the purpose of the code, then consider line-by-line comments, something like this: https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/156947/110050

Comment: I had the exact same reaction when I saw the code, ++

Answer (score 2):

Reusing the constant 1 for both `STDOUT_FILENO` and `SYS_EXIT` is confusing to the human reader. You should prefer to write clear code instead of using these tricks.

Same for the `jmp *%ebp`.

Comment: I definitely won't be using these "tricks" in a compiled language, but here there is no compiler to simplify human-readable code. I'm trading readability for performance here. The same goes with the jump, since there are only single-depth call stack the register is used for performance(avoids memory access). As an added bonus, this code is impervious to Remote Code Execution(RCE) via return pointers on the stack.